# c# BinaryReader still open after .close();

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that reads file after I select a file and write file in hex. Problem is `BinaryReader` still open after `.Close();` and it gives me `System.IO.IOException: the process cannot access the file` error when i try to write a file. I'm missing something?

[image]

Here is the code that read the file after i select file from dialogbox..

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(sfile.FileName));
string pted = null;
br.BaseStream.Position = 0x12;
pted += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
if (pted == "01")
{

}
else
{

}
br.Close();
```

And here is the code that writes file when you click a button

```
Stream st = File.Open(pathTextBox.Text, FileMode.Open);
st.Seek(0x12, SeekOrigin.Begin);
st.WriteByte(0x00);
st.Close();
```

Comment: `BinaryReader` implements `IDisposable` so wrap it in a `using` statement. Where does the writing code go? Is it after the reading code or inside one of those `if` statements?

Comment: Can you wrap your binaryReader in a using block or change the .close() to .dispose() instead and see if it generates the same error?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining. I've edited my question. I tried `.dispose()` it solves the problem but I don't know if i really should use `using` or just `.dispose()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add br.close in a try catch statement and dispose the binary reader after closing

for example:

```
try{
    br.close();
    br.dispose();
}
catch(Exception exp)
{
//Assuming you have included using 'namespace System.Diagnostics'
Debug.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
}
```

You can read more on BinaryReader [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First check if file is here, then try it with `using` directive.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Orgen:

```
if(File.Exists(@pathTextBox.Text)
{
  using(Stream st = File.Open(pathTextBox.Text, FileMode.Open))
   {
    st.Seek(0x12, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    st.WriteByte(0x00);
   }
}
```

the using() will take care of the disposable.